# Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add Interstitial Ads in my app , but it seems like they are deprecated or something like that , can someone help me.

I keep getting this error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'Flight Reacts'.
>
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd:19.7.0:.
>
> Required by:
> project :

I already checked the questions about this but the solution doesn't work for me

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    classpath 'com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd:19.7.0:'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used interstitial Ads in my project and it is working properly with this dependency.

```
 dependencies { 
 ..
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
}
```